# How to update View in response to LocationListener.onLocationChanged()?

Tags: android

An app I'm working on can't meaningfully launch until it has a Location from somewhere -- coarse, fine, it doesn't matter. It just needs one that isn't null. So, my Activity class is doing something along the lines of the following:

onCreate():

- instantiate LocationManager
- create Map so I can keep track of all the LocationListener objects for which I've requested updates.

onResume():

- Grab List of enabled LocationProviders from LocationManager
- Iterate through list. For each one, check whether there's already a LocationListener in the Map. If not, create a new one, register it for updates, and stick it in the Map.
- Render the View
- implicitly return from onResume(). I'm ashamed to admit it, but I have absolutely no idea what happens to the Thread at this point.

(in the meantime)

... LocationManager.onLocationChanged(Location) gets called. The original plan was to use my LocationManager's reference to the Activity object to call a method whose purpose was to update the view to reflect the new status. Apparently, that's not allowed by Android.

... the user clicks a button associated with one of the LocationProvider updates, and the program proceeds to finish launching, or the user gets tired of waiting, clicks cancel, and the program quits since there's nothing meaningful it can do without a location.

So...

1. What IS the proper way to have the main UI Thread(?) wait until another thread calls onLocationChanged() with the updated values, update the UI, then proceed to launch the next Activity's intent or call finish() depending on whether the user clicks a button associated with a Location or clicks cancel?
2. What happens if you request updates from a LocationProvider and pass it a LocationListener that's already registered to receive updates? Does it just replace the previous time and distance args with the new ones, or will it create TWO entries in the subscriber list, and call the LocationListener TWICE the next time the location updates?
3. What happens if a the app nullifies all of its references to a LocationListener while it's still registered for updates? Does it live on, Zombie-like, thanks to a reference by the LocationProvider? Or does the LocationProvider use WeakReferences for everything, so old, forgotten-about LocationListeners will just fall out of scope and be garbage-collected?
4. If the LocationListener-implementing class has a reference to the LocationManager, is the Thread that calls its onLocationChanged() method allowed to use it to change the current LocationListener's subscription terms? Or will that blow up with an angry warning, just like the attempt to update the View from a Thread of the wrong type?

Comment: Not sure if it's related but with your Map and different listeners probably you are trying to build a feature that exists by using `addProximityAlert` http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Comment: In regards to 1, if the problem is that you are getting an exception because you are on the wrong thread you can solve that by using the activitys runOnUiThread.

For 2 can't you just unregister your listeners when the main activity pauses?

Comment: I don't want to unregister them when the activity pauses (or even stops, for that matter), because I want them to try and live long enough to at least get one meaningful update cached in the LocationProvider so it'll be there to use immediately the next time I try calling it. The idea is to launch the listeners with 0,0 to mean "update now, d***it, and hurry!", then unregister them once they actually produce that update so they won't keep trying to update over and over, as fast as they can, indefinitely, if the app gets forgotten about/stopped with the listeners still registered.

Comment: @Pentium10: Oops, I think I wasn't clear... my "Map" object is a HashMap<String,LocationListener>, not a "GoogleMap". Its whole purpose is so I can create listeners and register them for updates, but be able to go back through the pile at a later point to see which ones still exist & need to be unregistered for updates.

Comment: But why do you need multiple listeners?

Comment: No single provider works everywhere. On my Hero, at least, GPS is almost completely useless indoors -- even near a window. Network usually works, but it's a distantly poor option of last resort. So, I iterate through the list of enabled LocationProviders, create a listener for each one, and register them all for updates so the user can pick the one he likes best. Basically, the workflow is "Waiting for GPS, but letting the user bail and go with a cached value or inferior option if he doesn't want to wait or GPS looks like a lost cause at that moment.

Comment: (checks Javadocs for Location again). Hmmm. Actually, I never noticed the call to getProvider() in the Location object (blush). ~90% of the reason for doing it was so I could create a LocationListener that knew where its Locations were coming from. Well, *that* just simplified my code a bit, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't "have the main UI Thread(?) wait". Your user experience will suck if you "have the main UI Thread(?) wait", because they will wonder why your application keeps crashing with "application not responding" errors. Instead, you display a `ProgressDialog` or something to let the user know to wait until you get a fix, and dismiss that dialog when the fix is in. There are other patterns here as well.
2. I'm not certain -- I always use distinct `LocationListener` objects.
3. Yes, it lives on.
4. AFAIK, there is no problem in, say, calling `removeUpdates()` on a `LocationListener` from within `onLocationChanged()`. Then again, I have not tried it. If it does complain (most likely with some form of `ConcurrentModificationException`), have `onLocationChanged()` call `post()` on your `MapView`, to schedule a `Runnable` to be invoked on the main application thread's event loop that will call `removeUpdates()`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying! I have all of your books (well, at least the Commonsware ones and your new Apress book). Is there a chapter somewhere that I've overlooked that explains what happens between the time the main thread reaches the end of onResume() & metaphorically falls off the implied "return" cliff into some unknown limbo, and the point where something causes it to launch into onPause()? I'm starting to think that I'm suffering from "HelloWorld syndrome" -- I've seen so many HelloWorld-like examples that I'm (continued)

Comment: starting to mistake them for the right way to create an Android app, and creating a horrid frankenstein-like app that's basically a string of HelloWorld Activities chained together via abused Intents in the process ;-)